# CMD start .exe with just one of multiple parameters

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I would like my batch script to randomly choose one parameter on its own (from around 70 parameters eg. param1 - param70), without my input.

In addition to the random param, the exe has more parameters which always stay the same.

I dont know how to put this in code.

Here's an example of my thought:

```
param1=--abc
param2=--mno
param3=--xyz

./example.exe --hello --world --(param1 OR param2 OR param3)
```

which equals to:

```
./example.exe --hello --world --abc
```

or

```
./example.exe --hello --world --mno
```

or

```
./example.exe --hello --world --xyz
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit system wise? You are using batch, to start a bash script?

Comment: From where does the batch/powershell script get your 70 parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can work in batch.You need to set each param though.

```
set /a numb=%random% %% 3
goto :param%numb%

:param0
Set "var=abc"
Goto :execute

:param1
Set "var=mno"
Goto :execute

:param2
Set "var=xyz"
Goto :execute

:execute
.\example.exe --hello --%var%
```

For 70 params you need to change `%% 3` to `%% 70`

Comment: So for params 1-70 it would be /a numb=%random% %% 70 right ?

Comment: @mandy that is correct. Also you will then only end up with `param69` label as we start at 0.

Comment: Cool stuff. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

In powershell:

```
$params = "abc","mno","xyz"

& example.exe --hello --world --$(Get-Random -InputObject $params -Count 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Handling 70 parameters Gerhards way will get tedious. I'd build a parameter array and get a random one.

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\04\27\SO_50059458.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

Rem Build param[] array and count params
Set Cnt=-1&Set "param= abc bcd cde def efg fgh ghi hij ijk jkl klm lmn mno"
Set "param=%param: ="&Set /a Cnt+=1&Set "param[!Cnt!]=%"
:: show array
Set param
:: get random # in Cnt
Set /a Rnd=%Random% %% Cnt 
echo Random %Rnd% out of %Cnt%
Echo .\example.exe --hello --!param[%Rnd%]!
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\04\27\SO_50059458.cmd
param[0]=abc
param[10]=klm
param[11]=lmn
param[12]=mno
param[1]=bcd
param[2]=cde
param[3]=def
param[4]=efg
param[5]=fgh
param[6]=ghi
param[7]=hij
param[8]=ijk
param[9]=jkl
Random 10 out of 12
.\example.exe --hello --klm
```

Comment: Upvote for insane organisation! `Q:\Test\2018\04\27\SO_50059458.cmd`

Comment: @JamesC. Lazy me, I have a function in my Powershell  profile and also a batch to create these subdirs and pushd there ;-)